# issue sorting an array of objects, different objects but same content

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, sorting

i have an issue sorting an array of objects, these objects are different, each one has it's own different objectId, however the content is the same for some objects, here the output of my print(Myarray) : an array of object type notificationManager

```
    [notificationManager, notificationManager, notificationManager,
    notificationManager, notificationManager, notificationManager, 
    notificationManager, notificationManager, notificationManager]
```

how ever, i want to group them because inside notificationManager i have attributes such as fromWho and forWho and Activity, so there are notificationManagers they have the same attribute fromWho, to the same user forWho and  the same activity, these are  meant to be regrouped, so logically speaking, i am going to need another array to add the unique values like this and keep track of how many occurence for each element

```
    myArray[i].fromWho
```

because sorting the array it self wont do any difference because from the appearance the array already contains different elements, it's the content of the objects is different, here is my code but surely it needs a lot of modifications

```
    private static func removeDuplicates( origArray: [notificationManager]) -> [notificationManager?] {

     //initialize an empty array with the same count as the original    array
    var completionsToSend = [notificationManager?](repeating: nil, count: origArray.count)

   var j = 0


    for i in 0...origArray.count - 1 {
        let currentElemnt = origArray[i]

        if i < origArray.count - 1 {
        if (currentElemnt.fromwho.username != origArray[i+1].fromwho.username && currentElemnt.forwho.username != origArray[i+1].forwho.username && currentElemnt.activity != origArray[i+1].activity) {
            j += 1
            completionsToSend[j] = currentElemnt;
        }
        }
    }

if j < origArray.count - 1 {
    j += 1
completionsToSend[j] = origArray[origArray.count - 1]
}

    return completionsToSend
}
```

and later i just call that function:

```
    let myArray = removeDuplicates(origArray: completions)
```

here is my notificationManager object too

```
class notificationManager: Hashable {
//MARK: Properties

var fromwho : PFUser!
var forwho : PFUser!
var type : Int!
var activity: ActivityModel!
var status : Int!
var date   : Date!
var transaction : paymentModel!
var participant : participantModel!
var hashValue: Int {
    return status.hashValue
}

init(fromwho: PFUser, forwho: PFUser, type: Int, activity: ActivityModel, status: Int, date: Date, transaction: paymentModel, participant: participantModel) {

    self.fromwho = fromwho
    self.forwho = forwho

    self.type = type

    self.activity = activity

    self.status = status

    self.date = date

    self.transaction = transaction

    self.participant = participant

}

//MARK: Inits
init(object:participantModel) {
    self.fromwho = object.participant
    self.forwho = object.activitymaker
    self.type = object.type
    self.activity = object.activity
    self.status = object.status
    self.date = object.updatedAt
    if object.transaction != nil{
         self.transaction = object.transaction
    }
    self.participant = object
}
```

can any one suggest any modification ? and thanks

Comment: can you show your notficationManager object  ?

Comment: yes sure i have modified the post

Comment: what is the unique id used in it

Comment: actually i am not using a unique id for this object

Comment: array foreach forWho and fromWho elements ?

Comment: sorry i didn't get the question Tobi

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185680/discussion-between-tobi-and-raddaoui).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright so filtering a new Array with no duplicates based on the `forWho`, `fromWho` & `activity` attributes.

I have created a simple model to simulate your problem, since implementing the exact same situation is a bit difficult, however lets dig into it.

```
struct Item {  // as your Notification object
    var id: Int
    var name: String
    var nick: String
    var activity: Int
}
extension Item: Equatable {
    static func == (lhs: Item, rhs: Item) -> Bool {
     let name = lhs.name == rhs.name
     let activity = lhs.activity == rhs.activity
     let nick = lhs.nick == rhs.nick
     return name && activity && nick
    }
}
// sample  array of objects
let items: [Item] =  [
    Item(id: 1, name: "foo", nick: "foo", activity: 0),
 Item(id: 2, name: "foo", nick: "foo", activity: 0),
 Item(id: 3, name: "bee", nick: "bee", activity: 1),
 Item(id: 4, name: "boo", nick: "boo", activity: 2),
 Item(id: 5, name: "bee", nick: "bee", activity: 1),
 Item(id: 6, name: "cee", nick: "cee", activity: 3),
]

// filtration.
var newItems: [Item] = []
for item in items {
    if !newItems.contains(item){
        newItems.append(item)
    } else {
       print("alreadyExisted")
    }
}
```

As you can see we are simply confirming to the `Equatable` protocol that allows us to compare custom objects or pretty much anything between the `==` operator.

above you can see i used it to return the `Bool` value of it based on if the `name`, `nick`, `activity`  on each `lhs`, `rhs`  are equal to each others.

and with that i could simply ask my `array` if it contains `item` in the `filtration` section above because it will check if the item already existed based on those attributes.

**Now**

for your case you make sure to confirm to the `Equatable`  protocol as above and perform your checking.

As your based attributes are not simple `Strings` or `Ints`
so you may have to confirm `Equatable` to those models too this should give you a big picture of how it's done.

> Test the code on Playground,

**Output**

> 2 items alreadyExisted,
>
> new Array   [Item(id: 1, name: "foo", nick: "foo", activity: 0),
>
> Item(id: 3, name: "bee", nick: "bee", activity: 1),
>
> Item(id: 4, name: "boo", nick: "boo", activity: 2),
>
> Item(id: 6, name: "cee", nick: "cee", activity: 3)]

Comment: it Worked,  i just changed one thing, i compared using fromWho and forWho only, it seems that it doesn't compare activity too so i had to remove it from the equitable extension